# Regex for stylelint rule

Tags: regex, stylelint

I'm using stylelint and I need a regex expression for it's max-nesting-depth rule to ignore selectors which begin with both `&:` and `@media`

https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/max-nesting-depth/

So far I've tried the below without sucess:

```
"max-nesting-depth": [3, {
  "ignore": ["/^&:/", "/^@media/"]
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"ignore"` secondary option of the `max-nesting-depth` rule [only accepts](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/tree/master/lib/rules/max-nesting-depth#ignore-blockless-at-rules) the `"blockless-at-rules"` keyword.

Instead, use the [`"ignoreAtRules"` secondary option](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/tree/master/lib/rules/max-nesting-depth#ignoreatrules-regex-string) to ignore media queries:

```
"max-nesting-depth": [3, {
  "ignoreAtRules": ["media"]
}]
```

It is not currently possible to ignore nested rules. However, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/2696) to add this feature. The issue is labelled as "beginner friendly", and would be a good first pull request if you'd like to contribute to stylelint.